# will ripped abs be a no-show if my body fat % is increasing?

Tags: abdominals, body-fat

So I'm a fit 21 y/o. I have good cardio ability (I can run 10K, swim 2.5k and cycle 150K)

I started going to the gym 1.5 months ago, my body fat % was measured at **11%** before I began and just like the trainer said it would, it increased to **13%**

I do a regular ab workout on my cardio days (along with squats, deadlifts, chin-ups and lunges on weight days)

My abs have a little definition but their not fully ripped. (I have a slight pinchable bulge at the naval)

Am I on the wrong road here? Will my abs be a no-show since my body-fat is increasing? Should I better my diet to stabilize or decrease it?

Comment: What are your goals?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Well mostly to be able to run a marathon (maybe full) but also have nice abs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is ok for that increase in fat percentage for the start. I have been through that too. Now my body fat have drop to 7% after 8 month of training. You just have go through this stage and u will find your abs start forming. Anyway is better to control ur diet. Get tips from some body builder on what type of food that will be better.

Comment: Yeah, a small amount of BF increase at the start of a strength training program is okay. You're just overfueling your body so it can make strength gains. You can fine-tune later.

Comment: @Sancho maybe u can help advice him on his diet. As i am not that good in controlling my diet.

Comment: @Sancho-if someone is trying to gain muscle mass, they are invariably also going to gain a bit of fat as well. So will this small increase in fat prevent the gains made in obtaining a sixpack? Thanks!